# Is there anyway to make `tar -xf file.tar output_folder` command faster for an uncompressed file?

Tags: linux, compression, tar

I'm working with a Linux system and frequently use the `tar` command to extract large .tar files.

I'm running `tar -xf file.tar output_folder` to extract a `.tar` file into a specific output folder.

I've noticed that the extraction process can be quite time-consuming as there are many small files.

Comment: Do you have control of the target filesystem, can you remount it with specific parameters?

Comment: First, ye cannae breaks the laws of physics captain, & second, tar is not the best archive method to use in the first place for such large quantities of data. You'll be better off in implementing a proper backup system & use it only in ad hoc.

Comment: @RomeoNinov No i do not have access to the target file system. It is a server that i have ssh access to only.

Comment: @Bib can you please explain further? why would i need backup?

Comment: I had a suggestion of making a docker image with data which can be mounted faster.

Comment: @AliWaqas, in such case you can't do much because you reach the filesystem performance limits.

Comment: @RomeoNinov is there a way to split the tar file and then do a parallel extraction?

Comment: @AliWaqas, no. `tar` is "stream" of consecutive files and small amount of meta information. And to search in the file where to split, generate new tar, etc, are quite intensive disk operations. Which at the end will take more time, compared to sample extract.

Comment: Thanks for your input. have a great day.